# Como generar intervalo de fechas desde una fecha inicio con un numero de meses

Tags: java, sql, phpmyadmin

necesito generar un intervalo de fechas desde una fecha inicio con el intervalo brindado,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, segun la foto capturo la fecha inicio y los meses que necesito el intervalo

```
    SimpleDateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String dateInicio = dFormat.format(datoFechaInicio.getDate());
   String meses = this.txtMeses.getText();
        int mes = Integer.parseInt(meses);
```

Ahora necesito registrar las fechas: 10/05/2020   10/06/2020   10/07/2020 10/08/2020

Como podría hacer eso, muchas gracias por su apoyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debido a que no se que vas a hacer con las fechas, una vez obtenidas para los meses siguientes, las muestro por pantalla.(Al final lo importante es el proceso de obtenerlas).

```
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            int mes = 2;
            String dateInicio = "10/05/2020";

            Date fecha = dFormat.parse(dateInicio);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(fecha);
            for (int i = 0 ; i < mes; i++){
                cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                dateInicio = dFormat.format(cal.getTime()); 
                System.out.println(dateInicio);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```